# Как повернуть треугольник к новой нормали?

Tags: алгоритм, opengl, геометрия

Жил был треугольник и была у него нормаль, но вот однажды нормаль изменила ему и стала смотреть в другую сторону, на совсем другой вектор.

Погоревал треугольник 1мс и решил тоже повернутся чтоб зажили они как и прежде.

Задачка:
Как повернуть треугольник к его нормали? что бы жили они долго и по перпендикулярному?

Comment: Существует бесконечно много центров, вокруг которых можно осуществить поворот. Для каждого будет свой результат.

Comment: А также бесконечно много углов поворота вокруг оси вращения направленной по нормали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- выбираем нулевую вершину треугольника A за базовую точку
- откладываем от неё произвольный вектор, перпендикулярный новой нормали и с длиной вектора AB
- вычисляем вектор AD , перпендикулярный N и AB', как их векторное произведение
- находим вектор AC' как линейную комбинацию AB' и AD, обеспечивающую нужную длину AC и угол AC'B'

Для других вариантов постановка задачи не обеспечивает достаточно данных.

Comment: натолкнуло автора на мысль разумную, и стал треугольник жить поживать и радоваться. Спасибо.